# How to skip repeated entries in a .csv file

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting. I have a text file containing a list of subdomains (URLs) and I'm creating a .csv file (subdomainIP.csv) that has 2 columns: the 1st column contains subdomains (Subdomain) and the 2nd one contains IP addresses (IP). The columns are separated by ",". My code intends to read each line of URLs.txt, finds its IP address and enter the selected subdomain and its IP address in the .csv file.

Whenever I find the IP address of a domain and I want to add it as a new entry to .csv file, I want to check the previous entries of the 2nd column. If there is a similar IP address, I don't want to add the new entry, but if there isn't any similar case, I want to add the new entry. I have done this by adding these lines to my code:

```
awk '{ if ($IP ~ $ipValue) print "No add"
            else echo "${line}, ${ipValue}" >> subdomainIP.csv}'  subdomainIP.csv
```

but I receive this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:2:       else echo "${line}, ${ipValue}" >> subdomainIP.csv}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                       ^ syntax error
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @helen, as a side note, I see you are trying to use shell variables in the single quoted `awk` script. This cannot work, as the expansion does not occur within single quotes. Try `echo "$PATH"` vs `echo '$PATH'` in `bash`.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis So what should I do? I'm very new to bash scripting.

Comment: You can try using double quotes to quote the `awk` script instead of single quotes. In that case, however, you need to escape the inner double quotes. Compare `echo hello | awk "{ print \"$PATH\" }"` vs `echo hello | awk '{ print "$PATH" }'` in `bash`. On the other hand, I've never seen using `>>` in `awk`. I don't even know if it has a meaning. So I can't help you more at the moment (also because I'm going to sleep, ahah). Also, I suggest that you try to isolate a single problem. At the moment the question mixes `bash`, `awk`, and other concepts.

Comment: Answering your original question, you need to quote the filenames in
the `awk` script like `"subdomainIP.csv"`. The bare string
is evaluated as an `awk` variable, which causes the syntax error due
to the dot in the string.

BTW how come do you think the code `if ($IP ~ $ipValue)` cheks whether
the `$ipvalue` is included in the `previous entries`? Moreover you are
not even assigning the variable `IP` to any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
declare -A seen                         # memorize the appearance of IPs
echo "Subdomain,IP" > subdomainIP.csv   # let's overwrite, not appending
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ipValue=                            # initialize the value
    while IFS= read -r ip; do
        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            ipValue+="${ip}-"           # append the results with "-"
        fi
    done < <(dig +short "$line")        # assuming the result has multi-line
    ipValue=${ipValue%-}                # remove trailing "-" if any
    if [[ -n $ipValue ]] && (( seen[$ipValue]++ == 0 )); then
                # if the IP is not empty and not in the previous list
        echo "$line,$ipValue" >> subdomainIP.csv
    fi
done < URLs.txt
```

- The associative array `seen` may be a key for the purpose. It is indexed
  by an arbitrary string (ip adddress in the case) and can memorize the value
  associated with the string. It will be suitable to check the appearance
  of the ip address across the input lines.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please tell me how I can find and select a line that its 2nd column is equal to the found ipValue?

Comment: Hmm.. it is surely possible but if you want to find the duplication in the 2nd column, I'd recommend not to skip the repeated lines but output whole lines and process the csv file later with Excel or whatever you like.

Comment: @helen your proposed edit will rewind the script back to the original state which I did not consider about the multiple-line response from the `dig` command. Are you okay with it?

Comment: @tshino Yes, that's OK. I solved that problem in different way.

Comment: Sorry if my question is too obvious, but what does "trailing -" mean here? I mean this line: `ipValue=${ipValue%-}                # remove trailing "-" if any`

Comment: @helen thank you for the feedback. In the previous loop we append IP addresses
with `ipValue+="${ip}-"` then the result string will look like:
`192.168.10.1-202.238.95.24-`. The code `ipValue=${ipValue%-}` removes
the last extra dash `-` as a finish-up.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code. Here's a few of them.

- If the `awk` script is in single quotes, as in `awk 'script' file`, any variables `$var` in `script` will not expand. If you want to perform variable expansion, use double quotes. Compare `echo hello | awk "{ print \"$PATH\" }"` vs `echo hello | awk '{ print "$PATH" }'`.
- However, if you do so, than the shell will try to expand `$0`, `$1`, `$NF`, ... and this is certainly not what you want. Therefore you can concatenate single- and double-quoted strings as needed, e.g. `echo hello | awk '{ print "$0:"$0 >> "log"; print "$PATH:'"$PATH"'" >> "log" }'`
- Based on what I see from [O'Reilly's *sed & awk*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do), when you redirect to file from within an `awk` script, you have to quote the file name, as I've done in the command above for the file named `log`.